# Как дождаться выполнения условия promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть promise и мне нужно дождаться, когда выполниться условие: элемент a существует, но когда его нет в консоль выводиться Promise {pending}, но он так и не дожидается, когда кнопка станет зелёной, почему? Как сделать так чтобы Promise ждал когда элемент a будет существовать?

```
    'use strict';
    const a =  document.querySelector('[data-style="JoinToBattleComponentStyle-buttonJoinA JoinToBattleComponentStyle-buttonJoin"]'); //експорт 1 кнопки
    const join = document.querySelector('[data-style="DialogContainerComponentStyle-enterButton"]')//кнопка которая нажимаеться когда нажались какиет-то из двух
    const b = document.querySelector('[data-style="JoinToBattleComponentStyle-buttonJoinB JoinToBattleComponentStyle-buttonJoin"]')//експорт 2 кнопки
    const req1 = new Promise(function(resolve){//проверя существует ли кнопка А аж тогда я виполню resolve так же и b 
    if(a){
        resolve()
    }
    })
    const req2 = new Promise(function(resolve){
        if(b){
            resolve()
        }
        })
    const req3 = new Promise(function(resolve){
        if(join){
            resolve()//здесь когда нажата или кнока а или б тогда здесь нажимеиться
        }
    })
    
    req1.then(()=>{
            a.click()
    })
    req2.then(()=>{
        b.click()
    });
    req3.then(()=>{
        join.click(
        )
    });
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok i did it !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Промисы нужны для асинхронных вызовов.

Попробуй написать функцию, в которой будут условия проверки твоих классов.
И запусти ее через setInterval.(не ставь слишком маленький интервал)
Функция будет раз в интервал проверять существуют твои классы на элементах или нет.

Если я не прав- поправьте

П.С. читать тяжело твое сообщение

у тебя же промис создается, сразу отрабатывает if, реджектится с ошибкой и дальше не идет

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно проверять наличие элемента постоянно с каким-то интервалом. И нужно каждый раз заново вызывать `querySelector()`, потому что переменная `a` не будет обновляться автоматически при появлении элемента.

```js
const selectorA = '[data-style="JoinToBattleComponentStyle-buttonJoinA JoinToBattleComponentStyle-buttonJoin"]';

const req1 = new Promise(function(resolve){
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(document.querySelector(selectorA)){
      clearInterval(interval);
      resolve();
    }
  }, 1000);
});

req1.then(()=>{
  document.querySelector(selectorA).click();
});
```